# Функция принимает список, а возвращает кортеж с максимальным и минимальным значение из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Нужно написать функцию, которая принимает список, а возвращает кортеж из с минимальным и максимальным значениями в списке. (список должен содержать `int`).

Что не так?

```py
list1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
for i in list1:
    if max < i:
        max = i
    if min > i:
        min = i
return tuple(list1[max, min]
print(f"Максимальное значение: {max}", "Минимальное значение {min}")

Много раз переписывал, потерял начало.
def list(myList:list):
    Max
    i = int(input(""))
    for i in range(len(myList)):
        if Max < myList[i]:
            Max = myList[i]
    return tuple([Max, Min])
mylist = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
print(f"Кортеж с минимальным и максимальным значением из списка - {MinMax(example(mylist))}")
```

Comment: это вы должны рассказать, что тут, по-вашему, «не так». а кто-нибудь после этого подскажет, как сделать «так».

Comment: А где, собственно, функция? Кортеж можно попроще организовать `return (max, min)`. Имена переменных только плохие, совпадают со встроенными функциями

Comment: Где инициализация переменных с плохим названием max, min?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать **желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку** и минимальный код для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код нужно изменить так:

```py
list1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]

def get_min_max(lst):
    max = lst[0]
    min = lst[0]
    for v in lst:
        if v > max:
            max = v
        if v < min:
            min = v
    return (min, max)

result = get_min_max(list1)
print(f"Максимальное значение: {result[0]}", f"Минимальное значение {result[1]}")
```

А можно воспользоваться встроенными функциями `min` и `max`:

```py
list1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]

def get_min_max(lst):
    return (min(lst), max(lst))

result = get_min_max(list1)
print(f"Максимальное значение: {result[0]}", f"Минимальное значение {result[1]}")
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Алексей если ответ вам помог, отметьте его верным нажав на серую галочку

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3 

from typing import List


def get_max(sequence: List[int]) -> int:
    """Return max value."""

    max_value = max(sequence)
    return max_value

def get_min(sequence: List[int]) -> int:
    """Return min value.""" 

    min_value = min(sequence)
    return min_value


def main():

    sequence = [i for i in range(14)]
    max_result = get_max(sequence)
    min_result = get_min(sequence)

    print(f'Maximum value -> {max_result}')
    print(f'Minimum value -> {min_result}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```